# Create New Crystal Report .rpt

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

can any one help how to fix this i cant new create a crystal report on visual studio professional 2015

crystal report 13_0_ 19

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kL8lo.png)

hope any can fix this i try fixing it many time even reinstalling the crystal report but still cannot fix

Comment: Don't think there really is enough info to help sorry, you're obviously missing a file the Crystal report designers requiring.  Have you tried running the installer with elevated privileges?  Maybe https://support.sap.com/en/product/support-by-product/01200314690800000341.html might be able to guide you